# Loop-Level Prefix-Sum: Messed up partial sums

Tags: c, recursion, openmp, prefix-sum

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void prefix(int n, int A[n]){
    
    //end of recursion
    if(n==1) return;
    
    int n2 = n/2;
    
    //Array split
    int L[n2];
    int R[n-n2];
    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<n2; i++){
        L[i]=A[i];
    }
    

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=n2; i<n-n2; i++){
        R[i-n2]=A[i];
    }
         
    
    //recursion
    #pragma omp task
    prefix(n2,L);
    
    #pragma omp task
    prefix(n-n2,R);
    
    #pragma omp taskwait
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i<n2; i++){
        A[n2+i]=A[n2]+A[n2+i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\n",A[i]);
    }
    printf("END\n");
}

int main(){
    
    int A[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    prefix(4,A);
    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d",A[i]);
    }
}
```

Outputs:
1
END
32
END
1
4
END
16
END
32
END
16
0
END
1
2
6
7
END
1267

So I know that the partial recursion sums are messed up due to 32 in the first right half. But I am currently struggling to find the reason. The initial algorithm uses arrays from 1 to n. Is it something with the ranges?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

Now I get:

1
2
END
6684773
7864425
END
1
2
3
7
END
1237

What is it causing to fail to calculate the prefix sum?

Solved it now:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void prefix(int n, int *A, int start, int end){
    
    //end of recursion
    if(n==1) return;
    
    int n2 = n/2;
    
    //recursion
    #pragma omp task
    prefix(n2,A, start, end-n2);
    
    #pragma omp task
    prefix(n-n2,A,end-n2+1, end);   
    #pragma omp taskwait
   
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i<n2; i++){
        A[end-n2+1+i]=A[end-n2]+A[end-n2+1+i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\n",A[i]);
    }
    printf("END\n");
}

int main(){
    
    int A[4] = {1,1,1,1};
    prefix(4,A,0,3);
    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d",A[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `n` is zero, you should return zero, not `A[0]` (which is an out-of-bounds access in that case, assuming zero-sized arrays are meaningful).  If `n` is one, then you can return `A[0]`.

Comment: The `prefix` function shouldn't be returning anything, since all three calls to `prefix` ignore the return value. Declare the function as `void prefix(int n, int A[n]);` and change `return A[0];` to `return;`.

Comment: The code doesn't properly handle odd values of `n`. Keep in mind that integer division truncates towards 0. For example, if `n=3` then `L[n/2]` and `R[n/2]` are in fact `L[1]` and `R[1]`. That's a problem since the starting value of `n` is 4, so the recursive calls are `n=2` and then `n=1`, and  1 is odd.

Comment: Compute `n2 = n/2` once, at the top of the function.  The two arrays will then have lengths `n2` and `n - n2`.  Note that `n - n2` will equal `n2` if `n` is even, and `n2+1` if `n` is odd.

Comment: What exactly `prefix` function should do? Please clarify it. Besides indexing problems, recursive calls using local arrays (`L`,`R`) does not have any effect on array `A` in `main`.

Comment: prefix should calculate the prefix sum.

Comment: Also  A[n/2+i]=A[n/2]+A[n/2+i]; should manipulate A in main?

Comment: So my question: Why does my code result in outputting 16 and 32?

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void prefix(int n, int *A, int start, int end){
    
    //end of recursion
    if(n==1) return;
    
    int n2 = n/2;
    
    //recursion
    #pragma omp task
    prefix(n2,A, start, end-n2);
    
    #pragma omp task
    prefix(n-n2,A,end-n2+1, end);   
    #pragma omp taskwait
   
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i = 0; i<n2; i++){
        A[end-n2+1+i]=A[end-n2]+A[end-n2+1+i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\n",A[i]);
    }
    printf("END\n");
}

int main(){
    
    int A[4] = {1,1,1,1};
    prefix(4,A,0,3);
    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        printf("%d",A[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the program in your answer does not give correct result if `n` is odd. For this simple task you do not need a recursive algorithm unless it is your homework and you have to use a recursive algorithm and OpenMP tasks. You should use a much simpler algorithm such as

```
void prefix(int n, int* A){    
    if (n>1) {
        int sum=A[0];
        for(int i=1; i<n;i++){
            sum+=A[i];
            A[i]=sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it work for odd numbers by just enlarging the initial array with a zero and remove it at the end?

Comment: No. For `int A[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};` your code gives: `1,1,1,3,4,4,6,7,7,9,10,10,12,13,13,15,16,16,18,19,19,21,25,26,27`.

Comment: If you need a parallel algorithm to calculate prefix-sum you can find many on the net, e.g.: http://www2.hawaii.edu/~nodari/teaching/f17/slides/L06-segmented-prefix-sums.pdf

Comment: Would work to enlarge it with 0 until the length is a potency of 2.